# how to get variables from column names

Tags: php

how to get variables from column names

```
$sq = "select * from arts where id = :aid limit 1";
$st = $db->prepare($sq);
$st->execute([":aid" => $id]);
$row = $st->fetch();
```

now, instead of:

```
$cat = $row['cat'];
$title = $row['title'];
$subtitle = $row['subtitle'];
... so on
```

I need something like:

```
foreach($column_name as $el){
    $var_name = $el;
}
```

Comment: `foreach ($row as $name => $value) { ... }`

Comment: You mean like https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php ?

Comment: If you mean you want to set a variable with the same name as the column name, this isn't the best idea.  Thats what arrays handle a lot better.

Comment: As the comments above show, your intention is a bit ambiguous here. Perhaps you could give an example of the *end result* you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's rarely a good reason to do this, just use the array.  However, you can use [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) from the keys if there is only one row as you show:

```
foreach($row as $key => $val){
    $$key = $val;
}
```

There is also [extract()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) but may be even worse practice.

Comment: thansk a lot. If I have a lot of columns - the code is much shorter - a good reason - isn't it?

Comment: @qadenza In general, variable variables are not very useful. How will the rest of the code use the variables if it doesn't know what the column names are?

Comment: @Barmar - of course I know the column names - this is a table for a blog - so - `id, date, title, subtitle...` as usual